# Data Alignment inside Table column

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table

I have one table in that I am repeating data inside column. One column have property and other have value of that property. I am getting problem when data wraps property and value not aligned properly. Below is my example.
[My example](https://jsfiddle.net/uLmafv10/)

```
    <table cellspacing="0" celpadding="0">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Property</th>
    <th>Value</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <div>Property 1</div>
    <div>Property 2</div>
    <div>Property 3</div>
    <div>Property 4</div>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div>Value 1</div>
    <div>Value 2</div>
    <div>Value 3</div>
    <div>Value 4</div>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Property 2</td>
  <td>Value 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Property 1</td>
  <td>Property 1</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color:#fff;
}

table{
  width:100px
}
table tr td,table tr th{border:1px solid #fff;padding:5px;}
table tr td div{
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  padding:5px 0;
}
```

Right now I have given fixed width to table to produce my problem. In this condition what should I do to reolve this issue. I want to align property and value equally with respective values. Please help.

Comment: That not really the way a table is supposed to work.

Comment: Very strange way of using a table. Can you provide a image of your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve your issue is to add a fixed `height` to your `table tr td div` rules, so that it aligns properly. So, you could update that specific rule to something like:

```
table tr td div{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 5px 0;
  height: 48px;
}
```

However, `<div>`s are not really supposed to go into tables. Maybe you need to rethink your table's structure, as this will have accessibility issues for sure.

Comment: Thanks @Angelos but I don't have idea about content length means Property name will come lengthy then height will not work in this condition what should I do.

Comment: @vedankitakumbhar Like I and others have mentioned, it might be better to use elements that belong in a table instead of `<div>`s inside of it. This is definitely an easier, more flexible and better way to deal with your issue.

Comment: Project is already build in this structure is there any way to do this using javascript or css?

Comment: Probably several, but they are too lengthy to outline here and they might be more problematic over time (i.e. using CSS Grid or Flexbox). Plus the semantics and accessibility will still be wrong no matter what. Best solution is to refactor the code. I agree with the "if it ain't broken, don't fix it" mentality, but this is clearly broken.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using a classic table with no random `divs` contained in your `td` elements? Consider the below:

```
<table cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>Property 1</td>
    <td>Value 1</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Property 2</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Property 3</td>
    <td>Value 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Property 4</td>
    <td>Value 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>

body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color:#fff;
}

table{
  width:200px
}
td {
  width:100px;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid white;
}
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8dyxqbkz/2/

Comment: Thanks @A Tom Called Stu but I can't separate them because property have common header in thead and value have common header in thead

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<tr><tr/>` tag for table row
and `<td><td/>` tag for table cell.

Let me show an example:

```
<table cellspacing="0" celpadding="0">
<tr>
  <td>
    Property 1
  </td>
  <td>
    Property 2
  </td>
  <td>
    Property 3
  </td>
  <td>
    Property 4
  </td>  
</tr>
<tr>  
    <td>Value 1</td>
    <td>Value 2</td>
    <td>Value 3</td>
    <td>Value 4</td>  
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Property 2</td>
  <td>Property 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Value 2</td>
  <td>Property 1</td>
</tr>
</table>
```